# I am trying to change dynamic URL automatically to static URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

Hey If somebody could check my code as to what is missing,
I am using the following code to convert my dynamic URL to static:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*).jsp$ /page.php?fid=$1 [L]`

But to open with static URL, static URL is to be entered in the address bar.
If dynamic URL is entered it does not change to static automatically but I want to change that automatically to static URL.

Dynamic URL: http://example.com/page.php?fid=926
Static URL: http://example.com/926.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect from /page.php?fid=123 to /123.jsp
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?fid=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.jsp? [NC,L,R]
#Rewrite /123.jsp to /page.php?fid=123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.jsp$ /page.php?fid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule matches only for path. If you want to match for query string, you have to do the following.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fid=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^page.php$ %1.jsp
```

Comment: Thanks Jannunen, but Its not working error: Not Found

The requested URL /2.jsp was not found on this server.

Comment: Tested on my server and worked quite right. You are sure you have the + also after \d?